# Integrate Okta with a Cordova App for IOS and Android

Tags: cordova, okta, okta-api, okta-signin-widget

Is there a way to integrate Okta with a Cordova App for IOS and Android.

Please share if there are any existing Plugins for this integration or any documentation.

Can you please help us?

Thanks and regards

I saw there are no plugins available right now

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to use Capacitor instead of Cordova? If so, OktaDev Schematics makes it easy to create an app with Okta or Auth0 support.

https://github.com/oktadev/schematics#ionic